# Transfer a file from guest to host in Vagrant

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine

Does anyone know how to transfer a file from my vagrant VM to my host machine?

Heres what I'm trying but its not working for me - No errors but the file is not appearing:

```
scp -i /Users/myuser/path/mypath/.vagrant/machines/proj/virtualbox/private_key -P 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/database.sql
```

I have also tried this:

```
scp -P 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/database.sql .
```

And I get the error 'scp: .: not a regular file type'

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to transfer from 127.0.0.1? That is always the IP of the machine you are currently on, so in this case the VM itself. So you are trying to do a local copy, essentially the same as `cp /home/vagrant/database.sql .`

You need to use an actual IP address of the host system for this to work, not 127.0.0.1 or any other of the 127.x.x.x. local loopback addresses